# forEach and ngFor Duplicates Data if New Data is added

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, loops

I experienced this scenario when a new data is added in my Firebase Firestore Database.

`forEach` will iterate the values of the Document (Firebase Document) while the `ngFor` will rendered the data in frontend. This duplication of data will only happen if the page is not reloaded and when a new data is added, if user reloads the pages, the duplication stops.

My wild guess here, it can be solved if the page can reload automatically but unfortunately the adding of data happens in other pages.

This is the image to understand more: (If you noticed, some of the data was duplicated in frontend but if the user reloads the page, it will go back to normal).
[image: Image sample]

**home.html**

```
<div *ngIf="!auth.canDelete(user)">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size-lg="3" size-md="4" size-sm="6" size="12" *ngFor="let o of orgInfo">
        <ion-card>
          <div class="container">
            <ion-img class="img" [src]="o.imageUrl"></ion-img>
          </div>
          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title class="truncateWord">{{ o.orgName }}</ion-card-title>
            <ion-card-subtitle>{{ o.userList?.length > 0 ? o.userList?.length : '0' }} member/s</ion-card-subtitle>
          </ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-content>
            <p class="truncateWord">{{ o.description }}</p>
          </ion-card-content>
          <ion-button fill="solid" class="ion-margin" expand="block" color="primary" [routerLink]="['/home', o.orgId]">
            <ion-icon name="open" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>View</ion-label>
          </ion-button>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</div>
```

**home.ts**

```
   
      this.organizationList.forEach(uid => {
        const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("organization").doc(uid);

        docRef.get().then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
               this.orgInfo.push({
                orgId: doc.data().orgId,
                orgName: doc.data().orgName,
                description: doc.data().description,
                imageUrl: doc.data().imageUrl,
                userList: doc.data().userList
              });

              this.orgInfo.sort((a, b) => (a.userName > b.userName) ? 1 : -1);
            } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
      });
```

Comment: What happens if you uncomment this line: //public orgInfo = []; ?

Comment: Oh its just my comment to understand the code. Thats not actually part of my running code. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Its not obvious from your code here, but I feel you are the one who is pushing data, that is already inside the orgInfo, can you check if data already exists don't push.

Comment: When is the method where you iterate over 'organizationList' called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a unique value that doc.data() returns, you can check if the orgInfo array already contains an object with such value, and push to orgInfo only if there's no such object:

```
if (doc.exists) {
    // assumption: doc.data().orgId is a unique value:
    if (!this.orgInfo.some(e => e.orgId === doc.data().orgId)) {
        // this.orgInfo doesn't contain the item, so we can add it:
        this.orgInfo.push({...});
    }
}
```